# Why is find + sed search and replace way slower than grep -r

Tags: bash, performance, unix, sed, grep

I'm trying to do a search and replace on a repository (around 200mB, 3000 files), and I found that it is really slow compared to a grep for the same expression. Even tough the amount of matches is pretty low (couple 100), so the replace part shouldn't slow it down much.

Commands used:

```
time grep -r 'home' .

real    0m0.228s
user    0m0.154s
sys     0m0.071s


time find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/home/test/g' {} \;

real    0m38.064s
user    0m8.893s
sys     0m28.552s


time find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/home/test/g' {} +

real    0m25.671s
user    0m5.654s
sys     0m19.968s


time find . -type f

real    0m0.090s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.028s
```

What is happening here ? And is there anyway to speed it up with a different command?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges in your example.

Comment: For starters, `-exec sed ... {} \;` spawns a subshell for every single file and `grep -r` doesn't. Here is an interesting article about why GNU grep is fast: https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

Comment: Also, `sed -i` has to copy each file that it modifies, `grep` just reads.

Comment: But is there an alternative search and replace that is faster then ? Mostly I've seen people recommend the find + sed version

Comment: @BenjaminW.:  no, its not a subshell, it is a `sed` child process and has nothing to do with the shell.  There are significant differences.  (without that "subshell" word then I'm sure you are correct)

Comment: @MichaelFivez:  there are an awful lot of inefficient examples around.  What happens is that someone finds something that works and sticks to it.  The fact that it might not be scalable or appropriate to someone else's workload is not their concern.  Unfortunately bad practice is rife - just look at the number of unnecessary calls to `cat` you see in books and elsewhere.

Comment: @cdarke You're right, child process. Not subshell.

Answer (score 1):

The slow part is probably `sed` rewriting every file -- it has to do this for every file, even the ones that don't match. If most of the files don't match, you should be able to speed it up by using `grep` to produce a list of matching files (you know this is fast), then feeding that to `sed` to rewrite them.

```
grep -r -l 'home' . | while read -r filename; do
    sed -i 's/home/test/g' "$filename"
done
```

The `-l` option to `grep` tells it to print just the filenames that match.

If you're using GNU `grep` you can make this even safer and more efficient by using the `-Z` option to null-terminate the filenames; then filenames containing newline won't be a problem.

```
grep -rlZ 'home' . | xargs -0 sed -i 's/home/test/g/ {} +
```

Comment: or `grep -rlZ ... | xargs -0 ...` which would also help speed up things with parallel option - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24979

Comment: On my system (Mac OS El Capitan), `-Z` means to act like `zgrep`

Comment: With some fixes you idea works amazingly :)
    time grep -rlZ  'home' ferguson | xargs -0 sed -i 's/home/test/g'
    real    0m0.293s
    user    0m0.150s
    sys     0m0.136s
(100 time speedup for this specific case over find + sed)

Comment: My specific usecase (bigger repo and more complex regex) went from 20 minutes to 13 seconds